# How to reserve a ticker symbol for an ERC-20 token?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, dapp-development, decentralized-exchange, polygon

Cryptocurrencies and tokens are identified by a ticker symbol like MATIC (Polygon), AVAX (Avalanche), and KSM (Kusama).

**How do developers reserve these ticker symbols** before or during their ICO so that websites like Coinmarketcap and Coingecko, as well as DEX's like Uniswap, can widely recognize and list them, especially for ERC-20 tokens? Is it site-specific, or is there an official crypto ticker registry somewhere?

Comment: Any news on this @user610620 ?

Comment: Only found out how the ticker symbol can be coded into an ERC-20 token's Solidity code, which doesn't exclude anyone else from using the same ticker symbol in their code. No one's responded here about the process of publicly claiming a ticker symbol however.

Comment: From what I understand there is no such thing as reserving a ticker symbol because only the address of the smart contract can be unique. And big markets recognize tokens not only based on the name or symbol but also by their address and by their adoption compared to others. And they 'recognize' these tokens only if they are adopted and/or backed by many/known people/applications/etc. But I still have some doubts. Check my question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118711/how-polymath-is-doing-ticker-symbol-reservation-on-ethereum